# Android SDK not installing components on linux (ubuntu)

Tags: android, api, sdk

today i was trying to update the components of my sdk as the new android 4.3 is out. But it can't be downloaded as i don't seem to have the proper flags (superuser) to do it. I have found many solutions how to fix this on Windows, but i don't see how i can use them to get a solution for my ubuntu-command-line.

is there a way to launch the sdk as superuser via command-line?
is that some trouble just with API18 or general issue?

**Errors:**

---

Preparing to install archives
Downloading Android SDK Platform-tools, revision 18.0.1
URL not found: /opt/android-studio/sdk/temp/platform-tools_r18.0.1-linux.zip (Permission denied)

Downloading Documentation for Android SDK, API 18, revision 1
URL not found: /opt/android-studio/sdk/temp/docs-18_r01.zip (Permission denied)
................

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there a way to launch the sdk as superuser via command-line?

```
sudo .../tools/android
```

where `...` is the path to your Android SDK installation. In your case, from the error message, this would appear to expand to:

```
sudo /opt/android-studio/sdk/tools/android
```

Comment: last update they had an issue with merging platform-tools and build-tools and i had to workaround it. maybe that is troubling me now :/

Comment: i used the command "android" in all varieties before i asked that question. It just says "command not found", though i see it in the folder.

Comment: @bofredo: You need to provide the path to `android`. If your current working directory is `/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools`, and you run `sudo android`, you will get "command not found". If your current working directory is `/opt/android-studio/sdk/tools`, and you run `sudo ./android`, it will run, unless you screwed up your installation. If your current working directory is anything, and you run `sudo /opt/android-studio/sdk/tools/android`, it will run, unless you screwed up your installation.

Comment: /opt/android-studio/sdk/tools, and you run sudo ./android  <-- this one is working. trying to figure why "sudo android" isnt; as my current researches proposed that last command :/

Comment: @bofredo: "trying to figure why "sudo android" isnt;" -- because Linux searches the `PATH` for commands, and `.` is not in your `PATH`. Again, this is standard Linux command-line operation.

Comment: now that is a nice braintwister. thanks for pointing it out. I will look into it!

Answer (score 0):

You might use "sudo" command.
Please take a look of the man page before.

Comment: @bofredo: "but i cant just type in "sudo sdk" or "sudo android update" etc" -- of course not. This has nothing to do with Android and everything to do with working at a command prompt in Linux.